# Devise/Rails: after_sign_up_path_for(resource)

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am using devise in my rails app to user sign up/in. On sign up, i want to redirect user to its profile page.

I did rake routes and for edit, root is :

```
/profiles/:id/edit
```

I wrote this in registrations controller:

```
def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
'http://localhost:3000/profiles/#{resource.id}/edit'
end
```

But it is not working. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

shouldn't you use:

```
def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  edit_profile_path(resource)
end
```

instead of hardcoded `http://localhost:3000/profiles/#{resource.id}/edit`

would be helpfull to have your routes file posted too.